# How can I stream data to Google Cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a contant stream of messages (json). I would like to store it in GCS and have one file per hour. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GCS Resumable Uploads to stream data, either via the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) or [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload).

By using a resumable upload, you can continue to append more data to the object until you want to close it, so you could continuously stream data to it in chunks and then finalize it after an hour.